# Styling one element with multiple selectors (sass)

Tags: css, sass

I've an element I want to style only if it's got two classes applied to it:

`custom-select-value--companies`
and
`custom-select-value--companies-disabled`

It's actually the pseudo element I want to style, and the following css works:

`.custom-select-value--companies.custom-select-value--companies-disabled::after { // Styles }`

It's probably very simple, but I was just struggling to translate that to sass and was hoping someone could help? The following doesn't work:

```
.custom-select-value {
  &--companies.&--companies-disabled::after {
    // Styles 
  }
}
```

Also, just wondered as I was writing this - what's the main element of a pseudo element called? "Parent" doesn't seem quite right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working by typing the second selector out in full:

```
.custom-select-value {
  &--companies.custom-select-value--companies-disabled::after {
    // Styles 
  }
}
```